# Read raw arguments passed to ruby script

Tags: ruby, scripting, console, arguments, parameter-passing

I want to read raw input to ruby script and pass it further.

In example:

```
script.rb -t test -a argument three -b test
```

In this script I need to have a variable with string `-t test -a argument three -b test` which will be parsed by other functions later on.

Standart `OptPartser` and `ARGV` functionality removes `-flags` from stream, or takes a lot of hardcoding...

Flags are not defined before and it should be treated as one.

Answer (score 0):

Check out Ruby's way-cool [OptionParser](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/optparse/rdoc/OptionParser.html) library.

It offers parsing of flags/switches, parameters with optional or required values, can parse lists of parameters into a single option and can generate your help for you.

Here are some samples to play with:

```
require 'optparse'
require 'yaml'

options = {}
OptionParser.new do |opts|
  opts.banner = "Usage: example.rb [options]"

  opts.on('-t', '--sourcename test', 'test') { |v| options[:test] = v }
  opts.on('-a', '--sourcehost argument', 'args') { |v| options[:args] = v }
  opts.on('-b', '--sourceport something', 'Something') { |v| options[:something] = v }

end.parse!
```